# How to convert date format in string using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, petapoco

I am using ASP.NET MVC with petapoco. I want to display data from database table in the view as it has date column and I want to convert that date format in varchar like `'dd-mm-yyyy'`.

My date column is `TransactionDate`.

My query is as follows, I have used `convert` function, but it is not working, my date column is still appearing with milliseconds like `/Date152235232/`.

Please help me with this and tell me how I can convert that particular `TransactionDate` column in the table to display date in the `'dd-mm-yyyy'` format.

```
var sql = db.Query("Select CONVERT(varchar, d.TransactionDate ,101), d.DocumentId, d.SurveyNumber, d.FullName, d.Location, documenttype.DocumentTypeName, d.VillageName, d.PlanNumber, d.OwnerName, d.ContactNumber, d.Email, d.Status, d.TransactionDate FROM Document d " +
                                $"INNER JOIN DocumentType ON d.DocumentTypeId = documenttype.DocumentTypeId");
```

Here in the query I am joining two tables to fetch data from the table to display it

Comment: You are much better off doing date (and numeric) conversions on the client. The client can then convert in the best way for the current user.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: i am using sql server

Answer (score 0):

If your filed is date type and you want formatting dd-mm-yyyy then
you should have to use

```
   select CONVERT (varchar(10), getdate(), 105)
 return :15-08-2018
```

but if you want dd/mm/yyyy then you have to use below

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), getdate(), 103) as date_conv
  15/08/2018
```

more about [date format](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: but where should i put my column name of date in above convert function

Comment: @prathamesh93 you will put your date column in place of getdate() position

Comment: @prathamesh93 does it  helps ? if it helps then accept answer please

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 105 will give you format dd-mm-yyyy: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/sql-server/sql-how-to-convert-datetime-to-formatted-date-string-dd-mm-yyyy/

```
CONVERT( VARCHAR, d.TransactionDate, 105 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning the date twice.  Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
select convert(varchar(10), d.TransactionDate, 105) as TransactionDate,
       d.DocumentId,
       d.SurveyNumber,
       d.FullName, 
       d.Location,
       dt.DocumentTypeName,
       d.VillageName,
       d.PlanNumber,
       d.OwnerName,
       d.ContactNumber, d.Email,
       d.Status
from Document d join
     DocumentType dt
     on d.DocumentTypeId = dt.DocumentTypeId;
```

Note the original `TransactionDate` has been removed from the query.  I also added a table alias for `DocumentType`.